# overridePendingTransition not working on android devices

Tags: android, transition

by default, new activity enter from right side, and exit right. I want it enter and exit form bottom, but I tried my best, I can only make it come from bottom, exit stay from right, here is my code. I need some help, thanks.

```
private void show() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(this, PromotionActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_bottom_enter,R.anim.slide_bottom_exit); 
    }
```

slide_bottom_exit.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="200%p" 
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">
</translate>
```

R.anim.slide_bottom_enter.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fromYDelta="200%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p" 
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">
</translate>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this code to make transitions and then tell me:

- when you want to appear your activity from bottom

  ```
  overridePendingTransition(R.anim.top_to_bottom_in,R.anim.top_to_bottom_out);
  ```
- top_to_bottom_in

  ```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:duration="1000"
      android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
      android:toYDelta="0%p" />
  ```
- top_to_bottom_out

  ```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:duration="1000"
      android:fromYDelta="0%p"
      android:toYDelta="100%p" />
  ```
- when you want to make exit you activity

  ```
  overridePendingTransition(R.anim.bottom_to_top_in, R.anim.bottom_to_top_out);

  -bottom_to_top_in

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:duration="1000"
  android:fromYDelta="100%p"
  android:toYDelta="0%p" />
  ```
- bottom_to_top_out

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:duration="1000"
  android:fromYDelta="0%p"
  android:toYDelta="-100%p" />
  ```

Comment: I pressed back button and it disappear, and then older activity appear, what is the proper time I can call overridePendingTransition methord? thanks!

Comment: so with the just upper solution worked? (on backpressed). if yes then mark it as accepted so that other viewer can make use of it without hesitation.